# How to serialise field with empty collection of object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, pojo, objectmapper

Here is my POJO:

```
public class Target {

    @JsonProperty(value="sizes",required=true)
    private Set<Size> Sizes;

    @JsonProperty(value="domains",required=true)
    private Set<String> Domains;

    // getters and setters

}
```

I initialize this POJO like this:

```
Target target = new Target(new HashSet<>(), new HashSet<>());
```

How to get Json from this object with empty fields? I mean smth. like that:

```
{"sizes":[], "domains":[]}
```

I tried use ObjectMapper with different parameters, but it was no useful..